# htaccess working fine on one server and causing redirect loop on other

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am have htaccess file(code below), using the same on two servers with the domain name change. It is working fine on one but give a Redirect Loop issue on other. The only difference is, on one server I am using the Domain name and on other I am using the dedicated IP address

Code:

WORKING CODE :::

```
RewriteEngine on

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

##below 7 lines used in live server 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ home/ [R]
RewriteRule ^home/$ page/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forms/$ site-forms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^media/xmlfeeds/$ page/index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\/?)$ page/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

NOT WORKING CODE :::

```
RewriteEngine on

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

##below 7 lines used in live server 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^108\.175\.155\.54
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://108.175.155.54/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ home/ [R]
RewriteRule ^home/$ page/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forms/$ site-forms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^media/xmlfeeds/$ page/index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\/?)$ page/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Thank You.

Comment: So in the second case the request is done using the raw ip address in the browsers URL line?

Comment: Yes. I have to till the setup is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is being caused by the following two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^108\.175\.155\.54
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://108.175.155.54/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

These say, "If the host is 108.175.155.54 then redirect to 108.175.155.54."

So comment those lines out on the live server. When you have a domain name, you can uncomment them and use the domain instead.

Comment: Thank You Mike.
I did the suggested, but now a unknown file type file is getting downloaded.